# Automatic connecting to a BLE device [Android]

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, device

I am working on an Android application that should automatically connect to the BLE device with a specified MAC-address.
Basically a scan should be running 24/7, and as soon as the device is discovered, the service should connect to it, and ideally stop scanning.

What I managed to do is the following:

```
public void startBluetoothScan() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!scanning) {
            service.startScan();
        }
    }
}
```

with this being the overall method:

```
private void configBluetooth() {
    BluetoothConfiguration config = new BluetoothConfiguration();
    config.context = getApplicationContext();
    config.bluetoothServiceClass = BluetoothLeService.class; // BluetoothClassicService.class or BluetoothLeService.class
    config.bufferSize = 1024;
    config.characterDelimiter = '\n';
    config.deviceName = "Your App Name";
    config.callListenersInMainThread = true;

    // Bluetooth Classic
    config.uuid = null; // Set null to find all devices on scan.

    // Bluetooth LE
    config.uuidService = UUID_HRS;
    config.uuidCharacteristic = UUID_HRD;
    config.transport = BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE; // Only for dual-mode devices

    BluetoothLeService.init(config);
    service = (BluetoothLeService) BluetoothLeService.getDefaultInstance();

    service.setOnScanCallback(new BluetoothLeService.OnBluetoothScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDeviceDiscovered(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
            Log.d("Found device address", device.getAddress());
            if (device.getAddress().equals(UserHRMAddress)){
                if (!deviceList.contains(device)) {
                    Log.d("Connecting to", device.getAddress());
                    connectDevice(device);
                    deviceList.add(device);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartScan() {
            Log.d("Started Scan", "now");
            scanning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopScan() {
            Log.d("Stopped Scan", "now");
            scanning = false;
            startBluetoothScan();
        }
    });

    service.startScan();
}
```

The method above is the usage of [this](https://github.com/douglasjunior/AndroidBluetoothLibrary) library that should make BLE easier (I tried it raw and liked it equally little) Basically the scan returns the same device about a thousand times in a few seconds, without having the chance to connect to it first. Is there a possibility to let every device only be discovered once while scanning? Is there a more appropriate way to implement a 24/7 search with automated connecting?

What I also found out is, that the BluetoothGattCallback onConnectionStateChange method does e.g. not get called when you simply turn the BLE device off, or if you enter flight mode. If it did that, it would make my life a lot easier.

The relevant parts of my BluetoothGattCallback method look like this:

```
@Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d("onConnectionStateChange", gatt.getDevice().getName());
                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                //mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d("Status", "success");
                heartRateService = gatt.getService(UUID_HRS);
                batteryLevelService = gatt.getService(Battery_Service_UUID);

                if (batteryLevelService != null) {
                    batteryLevelCharacteristic =
                            batteryLevelService.getCharacteristic(Battery_Level_UUID);
                }


                if (heartRateService != null) {

                    heartRateCharacteristic = heartRateService.getCharacteristic(UUID_HRD);
                    boolean res = gatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(heartRateCharacteristic, true);

                    try {
                        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = heartRateCharacteristic.getDescriptor(
                                UUID.fromString(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));

                        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

                        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "wuuuuut?");

                    }


                }

            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use connectGatt with autoConnect = true. That works on all Android versions and there are no restriction on usage compared to scanning, as introduced in Nougat. Doing that will tell the Bluetooth controller to connect to the device as soon as it detects an advertisement. Note that since the android api unfortunately lacks "address type" parameter when connecting to a specific BD address, you either need to be bonded with the device OR it must have been discovered by some Bluetooth scan since the Bluetooth was last time turned on.

Unfortunately you still need a Bluetooth state change broadcast receiver to restart everything when Bluetooth is turned on.

Comment: So once I discovered a device once, I can connect to it, and the autoconnect feature will automatically reconnect, as long as I don't turn Bluetooth off? What exactly do I need to restart once I detect that Bluetooth has been turned on again?

Comment: Yes it will automatically connect. If the connection gets lost for a moment you will get onConnectionStateChange with newState to disconnected. Once it reconnects you will get onConnectionStateChange with newState to connected. After Bluetooth has restarted you must close the old BluetoothGatt objects and create a new one with connectGatt. But before you issue a connectGatt you must either be sure the device is bonded or first do a scan which finds your device (which will let the android stack store internally the address type of the device (public/random)).